# Heroku, cron.rake and friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). 
There's a rake task for deleting old slugs ([from the docs](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#friendlyid_rake_tasks)):

```
rake friendly_id:remove_old_slugs MODEL=<model name> DAYS=<days>
```

It can be run via cron.

Do you know how it should be added to cron.rake (I'm on Heroku)?

Here is my cron.rake:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do

  ...
  rake friendly_id:remove_old_slugs

end
```

It produces an error:

```
"rake aborted! undefined method `friendly_id' for main:Object"
```

There is no error if I run it from the console (Terminal) like this:

```
heroku rake friendly_id:remove_old_slugs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do
  Rake::Task['friendly_id:remove_old_slugs'].execute
end
```

Comment: OK. I'll see the result tomorrow, when the next cron runs.

Comment: You can also invoke `heroku rake cron` to test it right away.